# NextJS - Build error on SSG project because of invalid argument

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build

I'm trying to build a website on SSG (static site generation) and I keep getting this error that has me dumbfounded. I also have the same project as CSR and SSR where whenever I build the website app, I do not get an issue and it's only with SSG. I hope that someone can explain to me why is the argument invalid.

> Build error occurred
> [Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, rename 'D:\joema\Documents\Programming_Stuff\Programming_Projects__New-Projects\pokemon-app\SSG.next\export\pokemon\Type: Null.html' -> 'D:\joema\Documents\Programming_Stuff\Programming_Projects__New-Projects\pokemon-app\SSG.next\server\pages\pokemon\Type: Null.html'] {
> errno: -4071,
> code: 'EINVAL',
> syscall: 'rename',
> path: 'D:\joema\Documents\Programming_Stuff\Programming_Projects\__New-Projects\pokemon-app\SSG\.next\export\pokemon\Type: Null.html',
> dest: 'D:\joema\Documents\Programming_Stuff\Programming_Projects\__New-Projects\pokemon-app\SSG\.next\server\pages\pokemon\Type: Null.html'
> }